# Perl and evaluating Dumper Results

Tags: perl

I make an API call to a third party and the results are returned to me in a hash value that I named %hash.

When I print the results using Data::Dumper I get the following results:

```
print Dumper %hash;

$VAR1 = '';
$VAR2 = {
     'Field1' => 'first result',
     'Field2' => {},
     'Field3' => 'random value',
     'Field4' => {},
     'Field5' => '102',
     'Field6' => '3600176056428',
     'Field7' => 'AhhRbwSXxIzaSZYuvgXE8AmAXUdy'
};
```

I'm not accustomed to Dumper returning two values. I printed the structure so that I could determine how to access the values it holds. I want to access the hash data structure in the second VAR ($VAR2). How exactly is this done? 
$hash{'Field2'} does not return any value (obviously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert hash to hash reference:

```
print Dumper \%hash;
```

Otherwise `%hash` is converted into list of key => value pairs. That's hash behavior in list context.

To access values you'll need to use following:

```
$hash{''}{'Field1'}
```

Because in fact you have hash of hashes.

Comment: Ivan, I just edited the first answer above. That is indeed what was happening. The API was returning a hash reference. Once I changed the variable to a hash reference and dumped it, it is now clear to me how to access the hash values. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your `%hash` contains one key -- the empty string, and one value -- the data structure you see represented as `$VAR2`. When you call `Dumper(%hash)`, the `Dumper` function receives your hash as a flattened list with two elements, so it outputs two values.

The more canonical way to use `Dumper` is to pass references to data structures:

```
print Dumper \%hash;
```

Comment: So how exactly do I retrieve the value for field2? Would it be $res->{}{'Field2'} ?

Comment: Actually, I'm realizing that if I change the data structure that receives the results to a hash reference then accessing the values is no longer a problem. I realize now that the results returned are a hashref and not a hash -- this removes the complexity of accessing those hash values. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your `%hash` has just one key `''` (empty string) which holds a hashref. It looks like this:

```
'' => {
     'Field1' => 'first result',
     'Field2' => {},
     'Field3' => 'random value',
     'Field4' => {},
     'Field5' => '102',
     'Field6' => '3600176056428',
     'Field7' => 'AhhRbwSXxIzaSZYuvgXE8AmAXUdy'
};
```

Go back to where you assign it and check if you maybe need `$hash` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily you would dump a hash by reference, so `print Dumper \%hash`.

As it stands, `Data::Dumper` will print a list of the hash keys and values, so it appears that your `%hash` has a single element with the empty string as a key.

You can access this as `$hash{''}`, so the values are `$hash{''}{Field1}` etc.